# Does the shipwreck from Rune's (from the Thieves Guild) past exist?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[Rune](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Rune) is a character you meet in the Thieves Guild.  When you speak to him, he tells you about his past:

> As a child, Rune washed up on shore after a shipwreck near Solitude, and was found by a local fisherman. Rune could not recall his past, but the fisherman found a rock with strange writing on it. The fisherman named him Rune.

Rune spends all his money trying to find out about his past.  Near where he stands, there's a [letter](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/No_Word_Yet) addressed to him:

[image: (Letter to Rune)]

I looked all over Solitude, but I can't find anything in any of the shipwrecks, and the Internet is turning up a blank.  Does this shipwreck actually exist - **is there any way we can help Rune?**

Comment: @desaiw I have also searched and searched in vain :(

Comment: I found a shipwreck near Solitude called Orphan's Tear and I thought that has got to be it. However, there wasn't anything about him. I also found a book at another shipwreck. On the inside there was a written note. It was from a wet nurse that served this family and she said that she had been trying to find this boy who's parent's were dead and she couldn't locate him. I mean come on! That has to be about him!

Comment: @user24771 Where's the source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope. There's no way you can help Rune.

There are a number of shipwrecks, and one of them might be the one in his past, but there is no explicit or implicit connection, and there is no loot or lore to indicate that this must be the case associated with any of them.

Comment: source​​​​​​​​?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I think it's going to be difficult to prove a negative, but [discussion on the topic](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Rune) has shown no promising leads as well as some theories like the runes being part of an expansion or something removed from the game mid-production.

Comment: I can't prove a negative buddy. I'm sorry, but you're asking the impossible.

Answer (score 1):

According to the guide, currently, no.

Comment: link?  If it's a physical book, what's the book's name/page?

Comment: the official strat guide. and the dlc portion the official forums

Comment: So then... you can provide a link...?

Comment: Where is the source?

Answer (score 1):

when you talk to rune he mentions a ship that sank, i have found all of the ship wrecks and only one of them is under water. but its not near solitude. it the pilgrims trench. maybe its it but i havent been able to reach it, Imperial, and i can give you the location to, its to the west of winterhold and its deep under water. from what i can see from the surface its been split in two, and it seems to be that the current is going to solitude. im not sure but maybe its it.hope this helps, and if it dont it may behold tresure.

Comment: Why can't you reach it?  Underwater breathing potions are easy to make.

Comment: I reached it (Waterbreathing, Candlelight, and Reynos' Fins from Apocalypse mod) and found no relevant loot. With a waterbreathing enchantment I might have looked harder.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot of research, and the only thing I found is that Rune is an Easter Egg. There's a scene in the movie *Spaceballs* where Lone Starr is telling Princess Vespa a very similar story. There are a lot of Easter Eggs in Skyrim, and this may be one, too.

Comment: -1 this rumor [appears](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Rune#Possible_Reference) to have started on GameFront, where someone stated *"Speak to him about his name and he will tell a story that is almost a word for word quote from the movie Spaceballs. From the scene when Loan Star tells princess Vespa about his childhood."*  However, if you compare [the movie script](http://sfy.ru/?script=spaceballs) *(ctrl+f for "LONE STARR Who knows")* and [What Rune actually says](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Rune), you'll see this is completely baseless.