# Sapphire - Is there anything else?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm talking with Sapphire in the thieves guild, and the only thing I can do is ask her about her name. Then she tells me the sad story about how she was kidnapped.

I just feel that there must be more storyline with her, but even after becoming the thieves guild master, I don't get anything from her.

So, is there more that I can do with her?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Just like Rune (another Thieves Guild Member with an interesting backstory), Sapphire does not currently have any quests associated with her past, despite above average character development thereof.

Comment: [Related question about Rune](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54159)

Answer (score 10):

In the Dragonborn DLC, it is revealed that Sapphire is [Delvin Mallory](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Delvin_Mallory)'s niece and the daughter of the Raven Rock blacksmith, [Glover Mallory](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Glover_Mallory).

This is revealed after completing [Glover's quest (Paid in Full)](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Paid_in_Full) on Solstheim by retrieving the improved Bonemold Formula for him. He will give the Dragonborn the key to his basement, which contains leveled loot, the unique Blackguard's Armor, and a [letter addressed to Sapphire](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Glover%27s_Letter). The letter details how Glover and Sapphire's mother met and fell in love, and how Glover believes he failed her for not being there to protect them when the bandits destroyed her village.

If you tell her this by bringing her [Glover's Letter](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Glover%27s_Letter), she will reward you with an [exquisite sapphire](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Dragonborn:Exquisite_Sapphire).

<sub>Sources: ["Sapphire (person)" article, UESP wiki](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sapphire_(person)) and ["Sapphire (Character)" article, TES wiki](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Sapphire_%28Character%29)</sub>

Answer (score -2):

There is more to the story...go to solstheim do the missions for the blacksmith. Later he'll give you a key to his basement...read the letter addressed to sapphire. It explains everything then give it to her
The mission will not show up so you're on your own

Comment: Why 2 dislikes?